# Why is this struct passed as argument of a function, change is values?

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I have this struct and this function:

```
typedef struct pares{
int x,y;
} PAR;

arvpre criararvore(
   int i, 
   int j, 
   char matriz[i][j], 
   int x, 
   int y, 
   int *c, 
   PAR vis[], 
   int k
   )
```

As you can see, I pass `PAR vis` as an array of structs. From what I've been taught, this way, the value of `vis` is declared outside the function; and therefore should remain unaltered, right?  For example, If it's all zero before calling the function, after the function they all should still be zero.  However, the values change after calling the function.

Here is the full code:

```
typedef struct arv *arvpre;

typedef struct arv {
   char valor;
   arvpre N[8];
   int flag;
}Nodo;

typedef struct pares{
   int x,y;
} PAR;

arvpre criararvore(
     int i, 
     int j, 
     char matriz[i][j], 
     int x, 
     int y, 
     int *c, 
     PAR vis[], 
     int k
     )
{
   arvpre a=NULL;
   int z;

   while (*c){
      if (x>=j || x<0 || y<0 ||y>=i || vizitado (vis,k,x,y)) {
            return NULL;
         }
      else {
            a=(arvpre) malloc (sizeof(Nodo));
            a->valor=matriz[y][x];
            vis[k].x=x; 
            vis[k].y=y; 
            k++;
            (*c)--;
            z=*c;
            a->N[0] = criararvore (i,j,matriz,x,y-1,c,vis,k);
            *c=z;
            a->N[1] = criararvore (i,j,matriz,x-1,y-1,c,vis,k);
            *c=z;
            a->N[2] = criararvore (i,j,matriz,x-1,y,c,vis,k);
            *c=z;
            a->N[3] = criararvore (i,j,matriz,x-1,y+1,c,vis,k);
            *c=z;
            a->N[4] = criararvore (i,j,matriz,x,y+1,c,vis,k);
            *c=z;
            a->N[5] = criararvore (i,j,matriz,x+1,y+1,c,vis,k);
            *c=z;
            a->N[6] = criararvore (i,j,matriz,x+1,y,c,vis,k);
            *c=z;
            a->N[7] = criararvore (i,j,matriz,x+1,y-1,c,vis,k);
            *c=z;

            return a;
         }
   }
}

int main(){
   int i,j,c, dimy=3,dimy=4, flag=0;
   PAR vis[23];
   char sopal[3][4]={{'o','r','c','a'},{'r','a','i','o'},{'a','t','n','s'}};
   struct arv teste;
   arvpre a;
   a=&teste;
   for (i=0;i<dimy;i++)
      for (j=0;j<dimx;j++){
         c=23;
         for (b=0;b<23;b++) printf("%d %d ",vis[b].y,vis[b].x);
         printf("\n");
         a=criararvore(dimy,dimx,sopal,i,j,&amp;c,vis,k);
         printf("Sucssess for %c! \n", a->valor);
         for (b=0;b<23;b++) printf("%d %d ",vis[b].y,vis[b].x);
         printf("\n");
      }

   return 0;
}
```

The program will seg-faults, however the array is printed a few times before that. It changes each time it is called.

Why is this?

Comment: Read about pointer and arrays first before going over structure.

Comment: @haccks i have already. Maybe i've been bad thaught but from what i understand, if i pass it the way i pass the arguments, there will be new alocated space for each one of them.

Comment: As a function parameter, `PAR vis[]` doesn't mean an array of structs rather it means a pointer to a `struct`.

Comment: Hmm i see, so if i pass it as "PAR vis" only, and call the function say as PAR vis[0], then i will have no problem, right?

Comment: Ok it doesn't... How do i make it create a copy of that array of struct then @haccks? I don't want the values of the array outside the function to be changed

Answer (score 2):

`PAR vis[]` in a parameter list is exactly the same as `PAR* vis`.

Any assignment through `vis`, like `vis [0].x = 1;` will change the parameters that you passed in the calling function.

Comment: Hi there @gnasher729... Hmm, well but i only treat it like a PAR vis in the function, not an array itself... right? When i acess "vvis[k].x=x" for example, i should be writing, in the copy the function created of that struct. Or not?

Comment: forget it, i'm passing it as an array... Ok, so you say if i pass it like "PAR vis" corresponding just to a struct and not an array, i won't have a problem, right?

Answer (score 1):

PAS is passed by pointer (array, but makes really no difference since it's the same thing in this case), meaning that the function has the access to the exact same variable. 
Passing by pointer means that only the address of that parameter is passed and is a convenient way to alter a parameter in a separate function.

If you would pass it by value - another way of passing data in C, a new local instance of that variable would be created and would only have scope until the end of that function. However the changes made to that parameter would not be visible outside.

There is another way of passing data not available in C - passing by reference. It it somewhat 'safer' way of passing parameters then by pointer because a pointer can receive a NULL parameter, a reference parameter can not.

Comment: Hi @Andro47, thanks for your explanation. Can you explain how would i pass this PAS vis[] by value instead of reference?

Comment: @PedroLino it is not possible to pass arrays by value in C. If you have an array you wish to pass by value, one option would be to wrap it up in a struct

Comment: @MattMcNabb ah i get it now. Thank you! I don't get why i get downvoted on the question... Seems like a good doubt to have :/

Comment: I didn't DV but this is kind of basic; whatever book you are learning C from ought to cover this topic early on

Comment: Well i'm learning it from university, and we have no books, so i guess that's a "good excuse" for not knowing xD But thanks for the explanation and the tips once again